# How to pass sql query in grails

Tags: sql, grails, grails-2.0, gsp

Currently I am working with grails and MySQL.i want to execute my own query example "SELECT fullName from User" while clicking an anchor tag.

its my example that i worked out

```
class InsertDataController {

def index() { }
def sample() {
    InsertData insertData=new InsertData();
    insertData.show();
}
}
```

Domain classes

```
import groovy.sql.Sql 
class InsertData {

def dataSource

def show(){
   System.out.println("demo show");
   def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def rows = sql.rows("SELECT fullName from User")

        rows.each { row ->
                System.out.println("demo data"+row.fullName);
            log.debug row.fullName
        }

        sql.close()
}


class User {
        String userName
        String password
        String fullName
        String toString(){
            "${fullName}"
        }
    static constraints = {
        fullName();
        userName(unique:true);
        password(password:true);
    }
}
```

can anybody suggest how to solve this 
i want to know how to write the controller and model for this

thank you,

Comment: Can't you get rid of `InsertData`, and just have your controller return `[ names: User.list().fullName ]`

Comment: I strongly suggest you to read the GORM manual. There's a lot of methods available to query data.

Comment: iam writing that query as example .Actually i want to pass my own query to execute.

Comment: Have a look at the filter pane plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/filterpane).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `def sql = new Sql(dataSource)` in domain class,

use `def sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)`

Your Domain class can be modified as

```
import groovy.sql.Sql 
class InsertData {
      
def dataSource
         
def show(){
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)
    sql.eachRow("SELECT fullName from User") {
        println "the fullname is ${it.fullname}"
    }
}
```

And your Controller

```
class InsertDataController {
    def index() { }
    def sample() {
        InsertData insertData=new InsertData();
        insertData.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The InsertData class would be a service (InsertDataService) and that would inject into the controller InsertDataController.  The class User would be a domain class.

Controller class would then look like:

```
class InsertDataController {
    def insertDataService

    def index() { }
    def sample() {
        insertDataService.show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inject the datasource for execute your custom queries, try this in your show method:

User.findAll("usr.fullName from User usr")?.each{user->
    println user
}